# Font problem with renderImage function pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have an error when i read a page from a PDF document. this page contains a bar code which is 
done with a font (AAAAAC+Code3de9). this error appear only when i use the renderImage function.
I use the 2.0.17 version of pdfbox-app.

```
*déc. 02, 2019 9:34:13 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
AVERTISSEMENT: Could not read embedded OTF for font AAAAAC+Code3de9
java.io.IOException: Illegal seek position: 2483278652
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.MemoryTTFDataStream.seek(MemoryTTFDataStream.java:164)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:352)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:173)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:150)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:79)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:27)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:106)
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OTFParser.parse(OTFParser.java:73)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:112)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:65)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createDescendantFont(PDFontFactory.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.<init>(PDType0Font.java:192)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:146)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:61)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:872)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:506)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:480)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:153)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:268)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:321)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:243)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:203)
at patrick.mart1.impose.ImposeKosmedias$1.run(ImposeKosmedias.java:370)
déc. 02, 2019 9:34:13 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 findFontOrSubstitute
AVERTISSEMENT: Using fallback font LiberationSans for CID-keyed TrueType font AAAAAC+Code3de9*
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please share the PDF. This is either a PDFBox bug or a corrupt embedded font.

Comment: here is a link to the page of the PDF with the bar code  [PDF Doc] (http://www.com121.fr/projets/lmai/page-kosmedias-24.pdf)

Comment: That PDF displays in PDFDebugger. I looked at the font resources and found a broken font (F2) with a similar name and exception. I extracted the font and it is really broken. DTL OTMaster 3.7 light refuses to load it. Either you got the wrong file or the file was replaced (according to the meta data it was created today). The visible barcode there is an image, not glyphs.

Comment: I have extract this page from a complete document (24 pg), so if the barcode is an image, how can i delete this broken font from all that document before display it with renderImage function?

Comment: If you delete the font from other pages where it *is* used, then you'll get more errors because the font (where it is used) is now missing. You could try to selectively delete that specific text by expanding the RemoveAllText.java example. (As it is, it removes all text. You could improve it by only deleting text from a font with a specific name). Of course this is risky.

Comment: I have inspect all the pages of the document (and others similars) and this font is never used, i don't know why she is in the document, the pdf are send by a website. I think, i can remove it safely from all the pages, but how, have you an example if it's possible ? thanks,

Comment: But you did get the stack trace when calling renderImage, so it IS used. Just not in the PDF you shared. So it would be useful to get the actual PDF.

Comment: the link to the complete document  [full PDF Doc](http://www.com121.fr/projets/lmai/full-kosmedias.pdf), I hope you find something that i haven't see or likely not understand...

Comment: The font is selected in the first page. However no text is printed. So for that file, it is just a warning on page 1. If you really want to do a lot of work for just a warning, then you'd need to remove the "Tf", but only if the name is "F2". Change the RemoveAllText example to only remove that and the two arguments. Delete the other code segments that delete text. If you want I can do this for you but not immediately.

Comment: It's not only a warning, when i compile and use the script it's blocking error. i have tried something like that to remove the font without success, so your help will be very appreciated when you will have little time   :                                                   
`code`  for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames())
         {            
          String resName = fontName.getName();             
   if (resName.equals("F2")) {                             
              res.getCOSObject().removeItem(fontName); 
              page.setResources(res);
      }
         }

Comment: OK will do... what you did is only the less important one - the content stream needs to be cleaned up. You deleted from the resources, but it is still referenced by the content stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the RemoveAllText.java example from the source code download. It removes the selection of F2 in the content stream, and also removes the font in the resources. It makes the assumption that F2 is not really used, i.e. that there is no text related to F2. Compared to the official example, only "createTokensWithoutText" has been changed. I kept all the names even if the meaning is different, except for the class name.

So this code is really just for this file, or for files generated similarly.

```
public final class RemoveFontF2
{
    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    private RemoveFontF2()
    {
        // example class should not be instantiated
    }

    /**
     * This will remove all text from a PDF document.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length != 2)
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0]));
            if (document.isEncrypted())
            {
                System.err.println(
                        "Error: Encrypted documents are not supported for this example.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
            {
                List<Object> newTokens = createTokensWithoutText(page);
                PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
                writeTokensToStream(newContents, newTokens);
                page.setContents(newContents);
                processResources(page.getResources());
            }
            document.save(args[1]);
            document.close();
        }
    }

    private static void processResources(PDResources resources) throws IOException
    {
        for (COSName name : resources.getXObjectNames())
        {
            PDXObject xobject = resources.getXObject(name);
            if (xobject instanceof PDFormXObject)
            {
                PDFormXObject formXObject = (PDFormXObject) xobject;
                writeTokensToStream(formXObject.getContentStream(),
                        createTokensWithoutText(formXObject));
                processResources(formXObject.getResources());
            }
        }
        for (COSName name : resources.getPatternNames())
        {
            PDAbstractPattern pattern = resources.getPattern(name);
            if (pattern instanceof PDTilingPattern)
            {
                PDTilingPattern tilingPattern = (PDTilingPattern) pattern;
                writeTokensToStream(tilingPattern.getContentStream(),
                        createTokensWithoutText(tilingPattern));
                processResources(tilingPattern.getResources());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeTokensToStream(PDStream newContents, List<Object> newTokens) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
        out.close();
    }

    private static List<Object> createTokensWithoutText(PDContentStream contentStream) throws IOException
    {
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contentStream);
        Object token = parser.parseNextToken();
        List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while (token != null)
        {
            if (token instanceof Operator)
            {
                Operator op = (Operator) token;
                String opName = op.getName();
                if (OperatorName.SET_FONT_AND_SIZE.equals(opName) &&
                    newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 2).equals(COSName.getPDFName("F2")))
                {
                    // remove the 2 arguments to this operator
                    newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                    newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);

                    token = parser.parseNextToken();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            newTokens.add(token);
            token = parser.parseNextToken();
        }
        // remove F2
        COSBase fontBase = contentStream.getResources().getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.FONT);
        if (fontBase instanceof COSDictionary)
        {
            ((COSDictionary) fontBase).removeItem(COSName.getPDFName("F2"));
        }
        return newTokens;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this document.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + RemoveFontF2.class.getName() + " <input-pdf> <output-pdf>");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still too newbie with pdfbox to write this code, but i try to learn. So this example work like a charm, many thanks for your help Tilman